# How should AJAX in WordPress work when there's no function to output?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I need to use AJAX in WordPress to call a third-party API, and then based on the response to then update the state of some checkboxes.

I've used AJAX before, but it has relied on the output of PHP function to be written back into the Ajax contents, which is not what I want here.

So my question is, at the moment this is returning a 500 error (but won't tell me which line its own).

I have a single PHP function that does the API call and returns the result, but I'm not sure where exactly to call this in the AJAX function (should this be in action var?).

I plan to add my jQuery checkbox state changes to the success condition of the AJAX, but so far all this is doing is trying to return (echo) the output of the function underneath the AJAX code.

```
// AJAX query to get current status
function io_operators_get_status_ajax_enqueue() {

    // Enqueue jQuery
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    // Add the AJAX inline script
    wp_add_inline_script(
        'jquery',
        '
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            var io_operators_status_update = function() {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        action: "io_operators_get_current_service_state_ajax"
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function(throwError) {
                        console.log(throwError);
                    }
                });
            }
            io_operators_status_update();
            setInterval(io_operators_status_update.bind(null), 10000);
        })
        '
    );

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'io_operators_get_status_ajax_enqueue');


// The output of the AJAX contents
function io_operators_get_current_service_state_ajax() {

    try {
        return io_operators_get_current_service_state();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return $e;
    }
    wp_die();

}
add_action('wp_ajax_io_operators_get_current_service_state_ajax', 'io_operators_get_current_service_state_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_io_operators_get_current_service_state_ajax', 'io_operators_get_current_service_state_ajax');
```

Comment: "how to use AJAX in WordPress to call a thirdparty API" - Can you clarify "third-party" in this context? You appear to be making a local AJAX call, so I would consider this a first-party integration. If you are talking about a plugin, that's a grey area. Or, are you talking about making an AJAX call to your own code, and that code then makes an API call server-side to a third party?

Comment: @ChrisHaas The second is what I'm doing. The AJAX call is the local Wordpress function, and then it calls a function I've written to then interact with a third party API function. But I think I've got things working a bit more now actually.

Comment: If the PHP code throws a 500, check **why** that happens. Usually, that's independent from the AJAX call (unless you forgot to send the proper data, which would make the problem unrelated to PHP itself).

Answer (score 0):

The output of the API call can be printed in the 'success' branch of the AJAX call. however if the server replies with a 500 error, the code from the 'error' branch will be executed. I suggest you fix the bug you have in the API call and try again later.
Is the API call of type POST ? That's probably why the server is returning the 500 error